# Как заэскейпить пользовательский ввод для LIKE?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, like, escape

Пишу приложение на ноде, в качестве драйвера бд импользую `mysql2`. ОРМ не импользую и пишу сырые запросы. Появилась необходимость написать приблизительно вот такой запрос:

```
`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name LIKE '%${ userInput }%'`
```

Если заменить `'%${ userInput }%'` плейсхолдером ? и передать пользовательский ввод вторым параметром в запрос, то сгенерированный sql будет невалиден

```
`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name LIKE '%'Mike'%'`
```

Можно ли заэскейпить пользовательский ввод для использования вместе с оператором LIKE штатными средствами библиотеки `mysql2`?

Comment: в mysql можно сделать что-то вроде такого `'%' || '?' || '%'`?

Comment: или даже так https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/master/documentation/Extras.md

Comment: или ход конём https://knexjs.org/ (queryBuilder не orm, так шта не зашквар)

Comment: @nörbörnën knex думаю надо будет затащить. ибо миграции